# mysql query failing due to "\" at the of one of string value

Tags: python, mysql

I am generating queries using excel sheet in python and then executing the query using `conn.execute(query)`.

However one query is failing because it has `\` at the end of one of the value string. Look for `VALUES ("test", "ABCD\"` in the query below:

```
INSERT INTO S_account(Sub, AccName, AccTeam, Terr, AccOwner,
Level1, GAccount, Customer, City, State, EndCusName, AccID)
VALUES ("test", "ABCD\", "test", "test", "test", "No", "Yes",
"test", "test", "test", "asdasdas")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
Sub = VALUES(Sub), AccName = VALUES(AccName), AccTeam = VALUES(AccTeam), 
Terr = VALUES(Terr), AccOwner = VALUES(AccOwner), Level1 = VALUES(Level1), 
GAccount = VALUES(GAccount), Customer = VALUES(Customer), 
City = VALUES(City), State = VALUES(State), EndCusName = VALUES(EndCusName)
```

I tried below command but it did not help.

```
query = re.sub('\$', '' query)
```

Comment: You should be using a prepared statement and parameter binding. I don't know Python but surely it has this feature

Answer (score 1):

You specified 12 columns in your `INSERT` statement, but you only included values for 11 columns:

```
INSERT INTO S_account(Sub, AccName, AccTeam, Terr, AccOwner, Level1,
                      GAccount, Customer, City, State, EndCusName, AccID)
VALUES ("test", "ABCD\", "test", "test", "test", "No",
        "Yes", "test", "test", "test", "asdasdas", MISSING)  -- no value for AccID
```

I don't think the backslash has anything to do with it.  Did your error message actually mention backslash as being a problem?

Comment: that ol' chestnut, well spotted

Comment: I missed out on it while typing here. Thank you for spotting it.

It actually stops right where it sees \ in one of the string value. 

Is there anyway I can replace \ every time a \ comes up at the end of string?

Comment: As a raw MySQL query what I gave above should run without error.  My guess is that if you have this query inside a Python string that it is interpreting `\"` as an _escaped_ quote.  Can you try just replacing these occurrences?  I'm not a Python person :-(